# Extracting custom attributes from script tag (not using data-)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have numerous sites with the following code:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-sidebar"....
<script async custom-element="amp-slider"....
```

How do I extract all the custom-element properties using vanilla JS only. There is no ID for the script tag and custom element-element is a non standard attribute (therefore I can add a data- prefix)

I have tried the following also, with no luck.

```
document.querySelectorAll('script[custom-element]')
```

Comment: BTW `custom-element` is an invalid HTML5 attribute

Comment: I know, but it's part of a plugin I didn't create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.querySelectorAll()` has no `.map()` prototype (unlike the `.forEach()`), the best is to destructure the *array-like* NodeList into an ordinary Array (using `[...NodeList]` or `Array.from(NodeList)`) and than use a `.map()` function *iterator*:

```js
const invalidAttrVal = [...document.querySelectorAll("script[custom-element]")].map(el => 
  el.getAttribute("custom-element") 
);

console.log( invalidAttrVal );
```

```html
<script async custom-element="amp-sidebar"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-slider"></script>
```

the above will create the following Array

> ```
> [
>   "amp-sidebar",
>   "amp-slider"
> ]
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Using_map_generically_querySelectorAll

https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrays--from-iterable

Comment: You my friend are amazing! Thank you so much, really appreciate it. Works like a charm